# R: use of ddply on a data frame with categorical variable

Tags: r, plyr

Right to the question.

I have a data.frame (structure as below) with mainly categorical variables (most binary i.e. yes or no and one with three levels (data.frame$tertile).

```
'data.frame'::

 $ smoker        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No"

 $ mi            : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No":

$ angina        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 

 $ pvd           : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 

 $ isch.stroke   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 

 $ ht.1          : Factor w/ 2 levels "Yes","No": 

 $ tertile       : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3":
```

I would like to produce a data frame with summary statistics of all the categorical variables i.e proportion of patients with yes grouped by `data.frame$tertile`.

Is it possible to use ddply for this for the categorical variables, I have managed to use ddply for the continuous variables using

```
x <- ddply(data.frame,.(tertile), numcolwise(mean,))
```

but finding it difficult to apply the catcolwise function and use ddply at the same time.

Thanks in advance guys and be grateful for any responses.

Regards

Anoop

Comment: It will be helpful if you could provide code to reproduce your data frame.

Comment: You seem to have mainly or only factor variables. What do you expect to be the mean of "Yes" and "No"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
 fun1 <- function(x) round(100*(table(x)/length(x))[1],2)
 ddply(dat, .(tertile),colwise(fun1) )
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(smoker = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor"), mi = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor"), 
angina = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor"), pvd = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"
), class = "factor"), isch.stroke = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor"), 
ht.1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("Yes", "No"), class = "factor"), tertile = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", 
"3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("smoker", "mi", "angina", 
"pvd", "isch.stroke", "ht.1", "tertile"), row.names = c(NA, -10L
), class = "data.frame")


  ddply(dat, .(tertile),colwise(fun1) )
#  tertile smoker     mi angina   pvd isch.stroke ht.1
#1       1   0.00   0.00  33.33 33.33        0.00    0
#2       2   0.00 100.00   0.00  0.00        0.00    0
#3       3  33.33  66.67  50.00 50.00       66.67  100
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
  dat%>%
  group_by(tertile)%>% 
  summarise_each(funs(fun1))
  #Source: local data frame [3 x 7]

 #   tertile smoker     mi angina   pvd isch.stroke ht.1
 #1       1   0.00   0.00  33.33 33.33        0.00    0
 #2       2   0.00 100.00   0.00  0.00        0.00    0
 #3       3  33.33  66.67  50.00 50.00       66.67  100
```

Comment: thanksa Akrun and BBrill...worked brilliantly and saved me a lot of time...you guys are legends.

Answer (score 0):

To know the proportion of "yes" and "no" count the number of time a logical evaluation gives `TRUE` (TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0)

`nYes <- function(x) 100*(sum(x=="Yes")/length(x)`

make some dummy data

```
vec <- c("Yes","No")
vec2 <- c(1,2,3)
tmp <- data.frame("smoker" = sample(vec,10, replace=TRUE),
             "mi" = sample(vec,10, replace=TRUE),
             "tertile" = sample(vec2,10, replace=TRUE))
```

Then use ddply

`ddply(tmp, .(tertile), colwise(nYes))`